# how to define CarInstrumentSimulator here

Tags: java

> 1.The FuelGauge Class: This class simulates a fuel gauge. It’s responsibilities are – To know the car’s current amount of fuel, in
> gallons. – To report the car’s current amount of fuel, in gallons. –
> To be able to increment the amount of fuel by 1 gallon. This simulates
> putting fuel in the car. (The car can hold a maximum of 15 gallons.) –
> To be able to decrement the amount of fuel by 1 gallon, if the amount
> of fuel is greater than 0 gallons. This simulates burning fuel as the
> car runs.
> 2.The Odometer Class: This class simulates the car’s odometer. It’s responsibilities are – To know the car’s current mileage. – To report
> the car’s current mileage. – To be able to increment the current
> mileage by 1 mile. The maximum mileage the odometer can store is
> 99,999 miles. When this amount is exceeded, the odometer resets the
> current mileage to 0. – To be able to work with a FuelGuage object. It
> should decrease the FuelGauge object’s current amount of fuel by 1
> gallon for every 24 miles traveled. (The car’s fuel economy is 24
> miles per gallon.)
> 3. Demonstrate the classes by creating a main class that creates instances of each. Simulate filling the car up with fuel, and then run
> a loop that increments the odometer until the car runs out of fuel.
> During each loop iteration, print the car’s current mileage and amount
> of fuel.

is what i had to do and i've got it down (at least I think lmao) but some of it is telling me like Cannot resolve symbol 'CarInstrumentSimulator' please take a look
here is my fuelgauge class

```
public class FuelGauge {
    final static int MAXIMUM_GALLONS = 15;
    private int gallons;

    public FuelGauge() {
        gallons = 0;
    }
    public FuelGauge(int gallons) {
        if (gallons <= MAXIMUM_GALLONS) {
            this.gallons = gallons;
        } else {
            gallons = MAXIMUM_GALLONS;
        }
    }
    public int getGallons() {
        return gallons;
    }
    public void addGallons() {
        if (gallons < MAXIMUM_GALLONS) {
            gallons++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Too much fuel");
        }
    }
    public void burnFuel() {
        if (gallons > 0) {
            gallons--;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Fuel");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarInstrumentSimulator carInstrumentSimulator = new CarInstrumentSimulator();
        FuelGauge fuel = carInstrumentSimulator.new FuelGauge();
        Odometer odometer = carInstrumentSimulator.new Odometer(0, fuel);
        for (int x = 0; x < FuelGauge.MAXIMUM_GALLONS; x++) {
            fuel.addGallons();
        }
        while (fuel.getGallons() > 0) {
            odometer.addMileage();
            System.out.println("Mileage: " + odometer.getMileage());
            System.out.println("Fuel level: " + fuel.getGallons() + " gallons");
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my odometer class

```
public class Odometer {
    public final int MAXIMUM_MILEAGE = 999999;
    public final int MPG = 24;
    private int initialMileage;
    private int mileage;
    private FuelGauge fuelGauge;

    public int Odometer(int mileage, FuelGauge fuelGauge) {
        this.initialMileage = mileage;
        this.mileage = mileage;
        this.fuelGauge = fuelGauge;
        public int getMileage () {
            return mileage;
        }
        public void addMileage () {

            if (mileage < MAXIMUM_MILEAGE) {
                mileage++;
            } else {
                mileage = 0;
            }

            int driven = initialMileage - mileage;
            if (driven % MPG == 0) {
                fuelGauge.burnFuel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if it's too long but i got to this point on my own and i am not sure why it is telling me stuff

Comment: Where is `CarInstrumentSimulator` defined?

Comment: Yeah I think you left out `by creating a main class that creates instances of each`.

Comment: ah it seems i forgot to include that, i will get on that, thank you

Comment: I will figure this out when I get home from work, i appreciate the help